# Wordpress error on 'edit image' and 'add featured image': shows "-1" instead of image

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

I am using WP 3.3.2 and the Thesis template 1.8.

Recently my server admin made a few updates of which details were not logged.

Since then WP has an error in 'edit image' and 'add featured image' in which when these functions are clicked, instead of the image showing, a '-1' shows instead.

I wonder if anyone here knows the inner workings of these functions so I can debug this issue and perhaps track the potential changes that were made to the server causing this WP error.

Note that these functions always worked correctly and my PHP code has not been touched.
PHP error logs show nothing on execution of this error.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my php.ini.

The following lines were like this:

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = ""
```

It says that `request_order` is OK to be empty as it will, in that case, use the `variables_order` directives. But that does not seem to be the case.

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP" (GP is the default)
```

made my server behave correctly and consequently WP now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky sometimes to locate a problem like this, however, I would give it a shot in the functions.php

Make sure that

`<?php function(){ ... } ?>`

`<?php function(){ ... } ?>`

looks like

```
<?php function(){ ... } ?>
<?php function(){ ... } ?>
```

With no spacing between them.

Comment: Also, check all files included within the functions.php.
Any errors or empty lines will cause errors in wp-admin.